# Should I set rewrite rules on an ASP.Net MVC site with heliontech IISRewriter Globally or by folder with wordpress?

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis-6, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite, helicontech

I'm using IIS6 (unfortunatly) and have built an ASP.Net MVC app; IIS is set up for wildcards to make the routing work but I have two virtual directories that contain wordpress installations which works fine.

I have two .htaccess files (one in each wp install) that handles their rewriting fine, but I want to setup a rewrite from /about to /blog/about. How would I do that and is it better to create all the rewrites in one .htaccess at the root of the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use separate files, it helps isolate problems if they occur.